Error in unity project using barracuda while trying to load an .onnx model
I'm getting an error

DepthwiseConv2D only support number of groups == number of input channels at the moment

when trying to use an .onnx model loading from Barracuda in Unity. How do I fix my model to accommodate this?
I'm trying to use the MiDaS depth estimation model.
Here's my script:
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Barracuda;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DepthEstimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NNModel depthModel;         // ONNX model imported as a NNModel in Unity
    public RawImage outputDisplay;     // UI element to display the depth map
    public Camera mainCamera;

    public int res;

    private Model runtimeModel;
    private IWorker worker;

    public float colorMult;

    public Texture2D testimage;

    void Start()
    {
        // Load and initialize the Barracuda model
        runtimeModel = ModelLoader.Load(depthModel);
        worker = WorkerFactory.CreateWorker(WorkerFactory.Type.ComputePrecompiled, runtimeModel);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Create RenderTexture and assign it to the camera temporarily
        RenderTexture renderTexture = new RenderTexture(res, res, 0);  // Adjust resolution as needed
        mainCamera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
        mainCamera.Render();

        // Set RenderTexture.active and capture the camera image
        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        Texture2D cameraImage = testimage;
        cameraImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
        cameraImage.Apply();

        // Clear the targetTexture from the camera to avoid conflicts
        mainCamera.targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = null;

        // Preprocess the image (resize, normalize, etc.)
        Tensor inputTensor = PreprocessImage(cameraImage);

        // Run the depth estimation model
        worker.Execute(inputTensor);

        // Peek output tensor and process it
        using (Tensor outputTensor = worker.PeekOutput())
        {
            // Convert the output tensor to a grayscale texture
            Texture2D depthMap = PostProcessOutput(outputTensor);
            outputDisplay.texture = depthMap;
        }

        // Clean up
        inputTensor.Dispose();
        renderTexture.Release();  // Release the RenderTexture to free GPU memory
        Destroy(renderTexture);
        Destroy(cameraImage);
    }

    Tensor PreprocessImage(Texture2D image)
    {
        int width = image.width;
        int height = image.height;
        
        float[] floatValues = new float[width * height * 3];

        Color[] pixels = image.GetPixels();
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
        {
            Color pixel = pixels[i];
            floatValues[i * 3] = pixel.r;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = pixel.g;
            floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = pixel.b;
        }

        return new Tensor(1, height, width, 3, floatValues);
    }


    Texture2D PostProcessOutput(Tensor output)
    {
        int height = output.shape.height;
        int width = output.shape.width;

        Texture2D depthTexture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24 , false);

        float minDepth = float.MaxValue;
        float maxDepth = float.MinValue;


        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                float depthValue = output[0, y, x, 0];
                if (depthValue < minDepth) minDepth = depthValue;
                if (depthValue > maxDepth) maxDepth = depthValue;
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {   
                
                float depthValue = output[0, y, x, 0];
                depthValue = (depthValue - minDepth) / (maxDepth - minDepth); 
                depthTexture.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.blue, depthValue));
            }
        }
        Debug.Log($"Sample Depth Value at (0, 0): {output[0, 0, 0, 0]}");   

        depthTexture.Apply();
        return depthTexture;
    }





    void OnDestroy()
    {
        worker?.Dispose();
    }
}

I tried to decrease the number of groups but that made a mismatch error. I expected it to make it work but it instead produced a separate error which is a whole different issue.
